# How to archive Azure blob storage content?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm need to store some temporary files may be 1 to 3 months. Only need to keep the last three months files. Old files need to be deleted. How can I do this in azure blob storage? Is there any other option in this case other than blob storage?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO best option to store files in Azure is either Blob Storage or File Storage however both of them don't support auto expiration of content (based on age or some other criteria).

This feature has been requested long back for Blobs Storage but unfortunately no progress has been made so far (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/7010724-support-expiration-auto-deletion-of-blobs).

You could however write something of your own to achieve this. It's rather very simple: Periodically (say once in a day) your program will fetch the list of  blobs and compare the last modified date of the blob with current date. If the last modified date of the blob is older than the desired period (1 or 3 months like you mentioned), you simply delete the blob.

You can use `WebJobs`, `Azure Functions` or `Azure Automation` to schedule your code to run on a periodic basis. In fact, there's readymade code available to you if you want to use `Azure Automation Service`: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Remove-Storage-Blobs-that-aae4b761.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Azure Blob is a appropriate approach for you to storage some temporary files. For your scenario, I assumed that there is no in-build option for you to delete the old files, and you need to programmatically or manually delete your temporary files.

For a simple way, you could try to upload your blob(file) with the specific format (e.g. `https://<your-storagename>.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/2016-11/fileName` or `https://<your-storagename>.blob.core.windows.net/2016-11/fileName`), then you could manually manage your files via [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/).

Also, you could check your files and delete the old files before you uploading the new temporary file. For more details, you could follow [storage-blob-dotnet-store-temp-files](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-dotnet-store-temp-files) and override the method `CleanStorageIfReachLimit` to implement your logic for deleting blobs(files).

Additionally, you could leverage a scheduled [Azure WebJob](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) to clean your blobs(files).

Answer (score -2):

You can use Azure Cool Blob Storage.

It is cheaper than Blob storage and is more suitable for archives.

You can store your less frequently accessed data in the Cool access tier at a low storage cost (as low as $0.01 per GB in some regions), and your more frequently accessed data in the Hot access tier at a lower access cost.

Here is a document that explains its features:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-cool-storage/

Comment: Yes I'm planning to use cool, but how do delete old data? data older than 3 months?